# on the non-normal subgroups of a finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, semidirect-product, solvable-groups

Let $G=P \ltimes QR=QM$ be a non-nilpotent solvable group, where $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n} \cong P=C_G(P)=N_G(P) \in {\rm Syl}_2(G)(n \ge 2)$, $\mathbb{Z}_{q} \cong Q \in {\rm Syl}_q(G)$, $\mathbb{Z}_{r}  \times \mathbb{Z}_{r} \cong R \in {\rm Syl}_r(G)$ and $M=P \ltimes R$ is a non-abelian maximal subgroup of $G$.

If $Q \ntrianglelefteq G$ and $R \trianglelefteq G$, then i want to find three non-normal non-conjugate subgroups of $G$ which are not cyclic.

**My try:** Clearly, $M$ is a non-normal subgroup of $G$ which is not cyclic.
Also we conclude from Frattini argument that $N_G(Q)=P \ltimes Q$ is a non-normal non-cyclic subgroup of $G$.

Since $G/QR \cong P$, $G^{\prime} \le QR$. By e Theorem we see that $Q=[Q,P] \le G^{\prime}$ and $R=[P,P] \le G^{\prime}$. Thus  $G^{\prime} =Q \ltimes R$. I need to find another non-normal non-cyclic subgroup.

Comment: Is there a comma missing between the $Q$ in $G=P\ltimes Q$ and the $R$ in $R=QM$?

Comment: It looks to me from your assumptions that you could have $Z(G) \cap P$ nontrivial. In that case, I think you could replace $G$ by $G/(Z(G) \cap P)$ and so assume $Z(G) \cap P = 1$. That could prossibly contradict your assumption $n \ge 2$, but I think that might be unnnecessary. Provided that $Z(G) \cap P = 1$, there will be a non-normal non-cyclic subgroup of order $2r$ (isomorphic to the dihedral group).

Comment: @Arturo Magidin No

Comment: @Derek Holt I'm not sure, Indeed, i think $Z(G) \cap P \ne 1$.

Comment: OK, well if $|Z(G) \cap P| = 2^m$, then $m<n$, because $P \not\le Z(G)$,and so the subgroup $H$ of $P$ of order $2^{m+1}$ will induce a group of automorphisms of $R$ of order $2$. Then $H$ must act nontrivially on a subgroup $R_1$ of $R$ of order $r$, and $HR_1$ is a non-normal non-cyclic subgroup of order $2^{m+1}r$.

Comment: @Derek Holt Thank you so much. Just if $|P|=2^{m+1}$ i.e. $Z(G) \cap P$, is maximal in $P$, then is it right?

Comment: I can't see any particular problem with the case $|P|=2^{m+1}$. In that case $H=P$ and $|HR_1| = |PR_1| = 2^nr$.

Comment: @ Derek Holt Yes, i got it. Thank you so much